# Entity Framework not performing migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a column that is set to a primary key, but is not set to an identity.  I am trying to convert it to an identity using the below method:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "ID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
    }
```

This runs without errors, but when I go to look at the column in the SQL Management Studio, no change to the column has been made, and the `__MigrationHistory` table shows that the migration was run.  What am I doing wrong?

edit:  my code first model has these attributes on the `ID` property:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Weird! Because int primary key are automatically marked as Identity.

Comment: I added the attributes and generated a new migration, but the code generated was just an empty Up/Down methods as if no change occurred.

Comment: Are you able to debug inside the method to see if it is getting called?

Comment: ahh, of course..you have to drop the primary key first...

Comment: Using SQL Management Studio, if you attempt to modify the column as you mentioned, do you get any errors?

Comment: You can't convert a column to Identity in SQL Server, as far as I know. You have to drop it and recreate it.